# Cilk installation error on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, cilk

I want to install cilk on my linux machine, and in their directory they tell me to write: `./configure` then `make` then `make install` to install the compiler on my machine, but when i type the `make` it gives a lot of messages, then at the end it gives me the following error:

```
Compilation Failed: 1 error, 0 warnings
Error: failed running cilk2c
make[2]: *** [fib.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/khaled/Desktop/cilk-5.4.6/examples'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/khaled/Desktop/cilk-5.4.6'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I downloaded the cilk directory from here: [http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/cilk/][1]

Is there a way to make it work? Also, is there a way to install cilk on windows too?

NOTE: I dont know if this matters or not, but I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 on VirtualBox.

EDIT:

I got the whole prints that I got after typing `make`, but I couldnt get the whole thing becuase i think there was not enough room, anyway here is from the top till the end of the statements I got:

```
mv -f .deps/libcilk_p_la-cilk.Tpo .deps/libcilk_p_la-cilk.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-sched.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-sched.Tpo -c -o libcilk_p_la-sched.lo `test -f 'sched.c' || echo './'`sched.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-sched.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-sched.Tpo -c sched.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_p_la-sched.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-sched.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-sched.Tpo -c sched.c -o libcilk_p_la-sched.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_p_la-sched.Tpo .deps/libcilk_p_la-sched.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-hooks.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-hooks.Tpo -c -o libcilk_p_la-hooks.lo `test -f 'hooks.c' || echo './'`hooks.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-hooks.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-hooks.Tpo -c hooks.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_p_la-hooks.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-hooks.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-hooks.Tpo -c hooks.c -o libcilk_p_la-hooks.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_p_la-hooks.Tpo .deps/libcilk_p_la-hooks.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-stats.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-stats.Tpo -c -o libcilk_p_la-stats.lo `test -f 'stats.c' || echo './'`stats.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-stats.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-stats.Tpo -c stats.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_p_la-stats.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-stats.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-stats.Tpo -c stats.c -o libcilk_p_la-stats.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_p_la-stats.Tpo .deps/libcilk_p_la-stats.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-barrier.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-barrier.Tpo -c -o libcilk_p_la-barrier.lo `test -f 'barrier.c' || echo './'`barrier.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-barrier.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-barrier.Tpo -c barrier.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_p_la-barrier.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-barrier.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-barrier.Tpo -c barrier.c -o libcilk_p_la-barrier.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_p_la-barrier.Tpo .deps/libcilk_p_la-barrier.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-cmdline.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-cmdline.Tpo -c -o libcilk_p_la-cmdline.lo `test -f 'cmdline.c' || echo './'`cmdline.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-cmdline.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-cmdline.Tpo -c cmdline.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_p_la-cmdline.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-cmdline.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-cmdline.Tpo -c cmdline.c -o libcilk_p_la-cmdline.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_p_la-cmdline.Tpo .deps/libcilk_p_la-cmdline.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-internal-malloc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-internal-malloc.Tpo -c -o libcilk_p_la-internal-malloc.lo `test -f 'internal-malloc.c' || echo './'`internal-malloc.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-internal-malloc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-internal-malloc.Tpo -c internal-malloc.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_p_la-internal-malloc.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-internal-malloc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-internal-malloc.Tpo -c internal-malloc.c -o libcilk_p_la-internal-malloc.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_p_la-internal-malloc.Tpo .deps/libcilk_p_la-internal-malloc.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-timing.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-timing.Tpo -c -o libcilk_p_la-timing.lo `test -f 'timing.c' || echo './'`timing.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-timing.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-timing.Tpo -c timing.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_p_la-timing.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-timing.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-timing.Tpo -c timing.c -o libcilk_p_la-timing.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_p_la-timing.Tpo .deps/libcilk_p_la-timing.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-invoke-main.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-invoke-main.Tpo -c -o libcilk_p_la-invoke-main.lo `test -f 'invoke-main.c' || echo './'`invoke-main.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-invoke-main.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-invoke-main.Tpo -c invoke-main.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_p_la-invoke-main.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-invoke-main.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-invoke-main.Tpo -c invoke-main.c -o libcilk_p_la-invoke-main.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_p_la-invoke-main.Tpo .deps/libcilk_p_la-invoke-main.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-malloc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-malloc.Tpo -c -o libcilk_p_la-malloc.lo `test -f 'malloc.c' || echo './'`malloc.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-malloc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-malloc.Tpo -c malloc.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_p_la-malloc.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-malloc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-malloc.Tpo -c malloc.c -o libcilk_p_la-malloc.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_p_la-malloc.Tpo .deps/libcilk_p_la-malloc.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-debug.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-debug.Tpo -c -o libcilk_p_la-debug.lo `test -f 'debug.c' || echo './'`debug.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-debug.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-debug.Tpo -c debug.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_p_la-debug.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-debug.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-debug.Tpo -c debug.c -o libcilk_p_la-debug.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_p_la-debug.Tpo .deps/libcilk_p_la-debug.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-workers.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-workers.Tpo -c -o libcilk_p_la-workers.lo `test -f 'workers.c' || echo './'`workers.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-workers.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-workers.Tpo -c workers.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_p_la-workers.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-workers.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-workers.Tpo -c workers.c -o libcilk_p_la-workers.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_p_la-workers.Tpo .deps/libcilk_p_la-workers.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-mutex.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-mutex.Tpo -c -o libcilk_p_la-mutex.lo `test -f 'mutex.c' || echo './'`mutex.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-mutex.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-mutex.Tpo -c mutex.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_p_la-mutex.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_p_la-mutex.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_p_la-mutex.Tpo -c mutex.c -o libcilk_p_la-mutex.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_p_la-mutex.Tpo .deps/libcilk_p_la-mutex.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -pthread -g -O2   -o libcilk.p.la -rpath /usr/local/lib libcilk_p_la-sysdep.lo libcilk_p_la-cilk.lo libcilk_p_la-sched.lo libcilk_p_la-hooks.lo libcilk_p_la-stats.lo libcilk_p_la-barrier.lo libcilk_p_la-cmdline.lo libcilk_p_la-internal-malloc.lo libcilk_p_la-timing.lo libcilk_p_la-invoke-main.lo libcilk_p_la-malloc.lo libcilk_p_la-debug.lo libcilk_p_la-workers.lo libcilk_p_la-mutex.lo   -lm 
gcc -shared  .libs/libcilk_p_la-sysdep.o .libs/libcilk_p_la-cilk.o .libs/libcilk_p_la-sched.o .libs/libcilk_p_la-hooks.o .libs/libcilk_p_la-stats.o .libs/libcilk_p_la-barrier.o .libs/libcilk_p_la-cmdline.o .libs/libcilk_p_la-internal-malloc.o .libs/libcilk_p_la-timing.o .libs/libcilk_p_la-invoke-main.o .libs/libcilk_p_la-malloc.o .libs/libcilk_p_la-debug.o .libs/libcilk_p_la-workers.o .libs/libcilk_p_la-mutex.o  -lm  -pthread -Wl,-soname -Wl,libcilk.p.so.0 -o .libs/libcilk.p.so.0.0.0
(cd .libs && rm -f libcilk.p.so.0 && ln -s libcilk.p.so.0.0.0 libcilk.p.so.0)
(cd .libs && rm -f libcilk.p.so && ln -s libcilk.p.so.0.0.0 libcilk.p.so)
ar cru .libs/libcilk.p.a  libcilk_p_la-sysdep.o libcilk_p_la-cilk.o libcilk_p_la-sched.o libcilk_p_la-hooks.o libcilk_p_la-stats.o libcilk_p_la-barrier.o libcilk_p_la-cmdline.o libcilk_p_la-internal-malloc.o libcilk_p_la-timing.o libcilk_p_la-invoke-main.o libcilk_p_la-malloc.o libcilk_p_la-debug.o libcilk_p_la-workers.o libcilk_p_la-mutex.o
ranlib .libs/libcilk.p.a
creating libcilk.p.la
(cd .libs && rm -f libcilk.p.la && ln -s ../libcilk.p.la libcilk.p.la)
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-sysdep.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-sysdep.Tpo -c -o libcilk_g_p_la-sysdep.lo `test -f 'sysdep.c' || echo './'`sysdep.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-sysdep.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-sysdep.Tpo -c sysdep.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-sysdep.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-sysdep.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-sysdep.Tpo -c sysdep.c -o libcilk_g_p_la-sysdep.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-sysdep.Tpo .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-sysdep.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-cilk.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-cilk.Tpo -c -o libcilk_g_p_la-cilk.lo `test -f 'cilk.c' || echo './'`cilk.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-cilk.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-cilk.Tpo -c cilk.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-cilk.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-cilk.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-cilk.Tpo -c cilk.c -o libcilk_g_p_la-cilk.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-cilk.Tpo .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-cilk.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-sched.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-sched.Tpo -c -o libcilk_g_p_la-sched.lo `test -f 'sched.c' || echo './'`sched.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-sched.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-sched.Tpo -c sched.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-sched.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-sched.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-sched.Tpo -c sched.c -o libcilk_g_p_la-sched.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-sched.Tpo .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-sched.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-hooks.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-hooks.Tpo -c -o libcilk_g_p_la-hooks.lo `test -f 'hooks.c' || echo './'`hooks.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-hooks.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-hooks.Tpo -c hooks.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-hooks.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-hooks.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-hooks.Tpo -c hooks.c -o libcilk_g_p_la-hooks.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-hooks.Tpo .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-hooks.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-stats.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-stats.Tpo -c -o libcilk_g_p_la-stats.lo `test -f 'stats.c' || echo './'`stats.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-stats.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-stats.Tpo -c stats.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-stats.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-stats.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-stats.Tpo -c stats.c -o libcilk_g_p_la-stats.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-stats.Tpo .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-stats.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-barrier.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-barrier.Tpo -c -o libcilk_g_p_la-barrier.lo `test -f 'barrier.c' || echo './'`barrier.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-barrier.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-barrier.Tpo -c barrier.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-barrier.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-barrier.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-barrier.Tpo -c barrier.c -o libcilk_g_p_la-barrier.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-barrier.Tpo .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-barrier.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-cmdline.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-cmdline.Tpo -c -o libcilk_g_p_la-cmdline.lo `test -f 'cmdline.c' || echo './'`cmdline.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-cmdline.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-cmdline.Tpo -c cmdline.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-cmdline.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-cmdline.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-cmdline.Tpo -c cmdline.c -o libcilk_g_p_la-cmdline.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-cmdline.Tpo .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-cmdline.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-internal-malloc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-internal-malloc.Tpo -c -o libcilk_g_p_la-internal-malloc.lo `test -f 'internal-malloc.c' || echo './'`internal-malloc.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-internal-malloc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-internal-malloc.Tpo -c internal-malloc.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-internal-malloc.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-internal-malloc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-internal-malloc.Tpo -c internal-malloc.c -o libcilk_g_p_la-internal-malloc.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-internal-malloc.Tpo .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-internal-malloc.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-timing.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-timing.Tpo -c -o libcilk_g_p_la-timing.lo `test -f 'timing.c' || echo './'`timing.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-timing.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-timing.Tpo -c timing.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-timing.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-timing.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-timing.Tpo -c timing.c -o libcilk_g_p_la-timing.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-timing.Tpo .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-timing.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-invoke-main.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-invoke-main.Tpo -c -o libcilk_g_p_la-invoke-main.lo `test -f 'invoke-main.c' || echo './'`invoke-main.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-invoke-main.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-invoke-main.Tpo -c invoke-main.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-invoke-main.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-invoke-main.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-invoke-main.Tpo -c invoke-main.c -o libcilk_g_p_la-invoke-main.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-invoke-main.Tpo .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-invoke-main.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-malloc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-malloc.Tpo -c -o libcilk_g_p_la-malloc.lo `test -f 'malloc.c' || echo './'`malloc.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-malloc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-malloc.Tpo -c malloc.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-malloc.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-malloc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-malloc.Tpo -c malloc.c -o libcilk_g_p_la-malloc.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-malloc.Tpo .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-malloc.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-debug.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-debug.Tpo -c -o libcilk_g_p_la-debug.lo `test -f 'debug.c' || echo './'`debug.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-debug.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-debug.Tpo -c debug.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-debug.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-debug.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-debug.Tpo -c debug.c -o libcilk_g_p_la-debug.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-debug.Tpo .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-debug.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-workers.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-workers.Tpo -c -o libcilk_g_p_la-workers.lo `test -f 'workers.c' || echo './'`workers.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-workers.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-workers.Tpo -c workers.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-workers.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-workers.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-workers.Tpo -c workers.c -o libcilk_g_p_la-workers.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-workers.Tpo .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-workers.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1  -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-mutex.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-mutex.Tpo -c -o libcilk_g_p_la-mutex.lo `test -f 'mutex.c' || echo './'`mutex.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-mutex.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-mutex.Tpo -c mutex.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-mutex.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DCILK_TIMING=1 -DCILK_STATS=1 -DCILK_CRITICAL_PATH=1 -DCILK_DEBUG=1 -pthread -g -O2 -MT libcilk_g_p_la-mutex.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-mutex.Tpo -c mutex.c -o libcilk_g_p_la-mutex.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-mutex.Tpo .deps/libcilk_g_p_la-mutex.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -pthread -g -O2   -o libcilk.g.p.la -rpath /usr/local/lib libcilk_g_p_la-sysdep.lo libcilk_g_p_la-cilk.lo libcilk_g_p_la-sched.lo libcilk_g_p_la-hooks.lo libcilk_g_p_la-stats.lo libcilk_g_p_la-barrier.lo libcilk_g_p_la-cmdline.lo libcilk_g_p_la-internal-malloc.lo libcilk_g_p_la-timing.lo libcilk_g_p_la-invoke-main.lo libcilk_g_p_la-malloc.lo libcilk_g_p_la-debug.lo libcilk_g_p_la-workers.lo libcilk_g_p_la-mutex.lo   -lm 
gcc -shared  .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-sysdep.o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-cilk.o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-sched.o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-hooks.o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-stats.o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-barrier.o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-cmdline.o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-internal-malloc.o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-timing.o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-invoke-main.o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-malloc.o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-debug.o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-workers.o .libs/libcilk_g_p_la-mutex.o  -lm  -pthread -Wl,-soname -Wl,libcilk.g.p.so.0 -o .libs/libcilk.g.p.so.0.0.0
(cd .libs && rm -f libcilk.g.p.so.0 && ln -s libcilk.g.p.so.0.0.0 libcilk.g.p.so.0)
(cd .libs && rm -f libcilk.g.p.so && ln -s libcilk.g.p.so.0.0.0 libcilk.g.p.so)
ar cru .libs/libcilk.g.p.a  libcilk_g_p_la-sysdep.o libcilk_g_p_la-cilk.o libcilk_g_p_la-sched.o libcilk_g_p_la-hooks.o libcilk_g_p_la-stats.o libcilk_g_p_la-barrier.o libcilk_g_p_la-cmdline.o libcilk_g_p_la-internal-malloc.o libcilk_g_p_la-timing.o libcilk_g_p_la-invoke-main.o libcilk_g_p_la-malloc.o libcilk_g_p_la-debug.o libcilk_g_p_la-workers.o libcilk_g_p_la-mutex.o
ranlib .libs/libcilk.g.p.a
creating libcilk.g.p.la
(cd .libs && rm -f libcilk.g.p.la && ln -s ../libcilk.g.p.la libcilk.g.p.la)
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/khaled/Desktop/cilk-5.4.6/runtime'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/khaled/Desktop/cilk-5.4.6/runtime'
Making all in support
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/khaled/Desktop/cilk-5.4.6/support'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I../runtime  -DCILKHEADER_DIR="\"/usr/local/include/cilk\"" -DCILK2C_DIR="\"/usr/local/lib/cilk\"" -DLIBS_DIR="\"/usr/local/lib\"" -DLIBS2_DIR="\"/usr/local/lib/cilk\""   -g -O2 -MT cilkc-cilkc.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/cilkc-cilkc.Tpo -c -o cilkc-cilkc.o `test -f 'cilkc.c' || echo './'`cilkc.c
mv -f .deps/cilkc-cilkc.Tpo .deps/cilkc-cilkc.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I../runtime  -DCILKHEADER_DIR="\"/usr/local/include/cilk\"" -DCILK2C_DIR="\"/usr/local/lib/cilk\"" -DLIBS_DIR="\"/usr/local/lib\"" -DLIBS2_DIR="\"/usr/local/lib/cilk\""   -g -O2 -MT cilkc-make-temp-file.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/cilkc-make-temp-file.Tpo -c -o cilkc-make-temp-file.o `test -f 'make-temp-file.c' || echo './'`make-temp-file.c
mv -f .deps/cilkc-make-temp-file.Tpo .deps/cilkc-make-temp-file.Po
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o cilkc cilkc-cilkc.o cilkc-make-temp-file.o  -lm 
mkdir .libs
gcc -g -O2 -o cilkc cilkc-cilkc.o cilkc-make-temp-file.o  -lm
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I../runtime  -DCILKHEADER_DIR="\"`(cd ..; pwd)`/runtime\"" -DCILK_RTSBUILD_DIR="\"`(cd ..; pwd)`/runtime\"" -DCILK2C_DIR="\"`(cd ..; pwd)`/cilk2c\"" -DLIBS_DIR="\"`(cd ..; pwd)`/runtime/.libs\"" -DLIBS2_DIR="\"`(cd ..; pwd)`/runtime\""   -g -O2 -MT cilkclocal-cilkc.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/cilkclocal-cilkc.Tpo -c -o cilkclocal-cilkc.o `test -f 'cilkc.c' || echo './'`cilkc.c
mv -f .deps/cilkclocal-cilkc.Tpo .deps/cilkclocal-cilkc.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I../runtime  -DCILKHEADER_DIR="\"`(cd ..; pwd)`/runtime\"" -DCILK_RTSBUILD_DIR="\"`(cd ..; pwd)`/runtime\"" -DCILK2C_DIR="\"`(cd ..; pwd)`/cilk2c\"" -DLIBS_DIR="\"`(cd ..; pwd)`/runtime/.libs\"" -DLIBS2_DIR="\"`(cd ..; pwd)`/runtime\""   -g -O2 -MT cilkclocal-make-temp-file.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/cilkclocal-make-temp-file.Tpo -c -o cilkclocal-make-temp-file.o `test -f 'make-temp-file.c' || echo './'`make-temp-file.c
mv -f .deps/cilkclocal-make-temp-file.Tpo .deps/cilkclocal-make-temp-file.Po
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o cilkclocal cilkclocal-cilkc.o cilkclocal-make-temp-file.o  -lm 
gcc -g -O2 -o cilkclocal cilkclocal-cilkc.o cilkclocal-make-temp-file.o  -lm
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/khaled/Desktop/cilk-5.4.6/support'
Making all in examples
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/khaled/Desktop/cilk-5.4.6/examples'
../support/cilkclocal -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I../runtime     -g -O2 -c -o hello.o hello.cilk
../support/cilkclocal  -g -O2   -o hello hello.o  -lm 
../support/cilkclocal -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I../runtime     -g -O2 -c -o fib.o fib.cilk
/usr/include/i386-li
```

Comment: Is this the whole output of make? Does configure print any errors?

Comment: configure prints out some messages too like checking stuff, and in make it gives some compiling i think, and then it gives this error

Comment: aizen, this log is not from configure, it is from make. Please, show us more lines from make's messages.

Comment: @osgx Yes this is from `make`, and ill post the whole prints i got after typing `make`

Comment: If total log is too long, post only the *last* 30-50 strings of log. Or you can upload full log to pastebin or other text storage online service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same problem on Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64. Solved it by adding some values to the CFLAGS variable in the configure step,

```
./configure CFLAGS="-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L"
```

Hopefully it will work for you too. Originally got the answer from here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.os.linux.development.apps/UiqFsaH69Aw

--xkcdcode

Comment: This is also worked for me but I am not able to compile program cilkc fib.cilk shows following error /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/waitstatus.h:76: syntax error. Any solution? My system is 32 bit Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Ok I fixed it. It seems there are some unwanted lines in waitstatus.h file. Comment those out. It will work fine.